# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error, cada vez que intento instalar un paquete en r?

Tags: r

```
library(dplyr)
```

me aparece este error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j
>   <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
>   is no package called ‘glue’ In addition: Warning message: package
>   ‘dplyr’ was built under R versión 3.5.3

también me paso cuando intente instalar `modeest` al momento de usar la unción `mfv` me mando el mismo error

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor edita tu preguna y agrega mas informacion... tambien que des formato a tu error para una mejor lectura del mismo.

Comment: Yo arrancaría por lo básico `install.package(dplyr)`, eso debería reinstalarte de 0 este paquete, adjunta cualquier error que te dé.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar instalar por separado glue con

```
install.packages("glue")
```

o puedes tratar de actualizar todos tus paquetes con

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

otra opción es probar instalar la versión en desarrollo desde github con

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/glue")
```

Comment: Tenía el mismo problema con varios paquetes y con actualizarlos todos solucioné el problema, aunque tardó unos 10 minutos.